# IF statement only executes if it's preceded with a 'sysout' of the value it is testing against

Tags: java, multithreading, if-statement

I'm getting a very strange error. I have the following code:

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println(model.getLightState());
    if (model.getLightState() == 1) {
        System.out.println("Entered..");
        view.driveThroughJunction();
        break;
    }
}
```

Now, my program enters the if statement when the light state changes to '1' and executes the code that's fine. But this ONLY works if I have that print out statement after the while loop is entered. I find that weird. Will a 'sysout' line have any effect on the if statement? Apparently it does for the above case.

Any ideas to why this is ?

EDIT:

```
(in the model class)
public final byte getLightState() {
    return lightChanger.getLightValue();
}

(in lightchanger class)
public byte getLightValue() {
    return light.getState();
}

(in the light class)
public final byte getState() {
    return this.state;
}
```

Comment: Are you changing anything in `getLightState`?

Comment: Show us your `getLightState()`.

Comment: No that method simply gets the current light state.

Comment: Are you running this code in a separate thread by chance?

Comment: See edit.

Yes it's a seperate thread.

Comment: Hi Jatt ,

It's works fine .  `if` condition only depends on given condition not  `System.out.println` .  May be you can post your Full java code it will helps to find it.

Comment: Can you try declaring model instance as volatile?

Comment: @bharathi I know. But the strange thing is that the if statement ONLY gets executed if there is a sysout before? I find this really strange!

Comment: @anubhava It worked! Can you please provide it as an answer and explain. Thanks.

Comment: @jatt Can you post your full code . It might be help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a synchronization problem, leading to a **visibility** problem. If no synchronization is used when reading and writing a variable shared by multiple threads, there is no guarantee that the value written by one thread is visible to other threads.

To fix that you need to do one of those things:

- make the `state` field `volatile`
- change the `state` field type to `AtomicInteger`
- synchronize every access to the `state` field (using the `synchronized` keyword), using the same lock every time, of course.

Your sysout call makes the value visible because it internally calls some method that flushes the state of the registers to the main memory (by writing to a volatile field or calling a synchronized method, for example).

Answer (score 2):

You should declare your model instance as **volatile**.

Volatile keyword in Java is used as an indicator to Java compiler and  Thread that do not cache value of this variable and always read it from main memory. So if you want to share any variable in which read and write operation is atomic by implementation you should declare them as volatile variable.

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/volatile-keyword-java-example-tutorial.html#ixzz2DFw4l8AW

From your comments it is apparent that more than one thread is accessing the same instance of model and performing read/write in the same instance of model. Without **volatile** threads do cache the value of model instance and hence end up in dirty reads. With `System.out.println` happening your read/write operation is delayed by a bit (due to output writing) hence thread is able to refresh the cached value from main memory.

Comment: Making model volatile is not going to solve the issue - he is accessing another variable. If it does solve the issue it is pure coincidence. The other answer is correct.

Comment: May be you can explain this `pure coincidence` theory better. And btw other answer also recommends using volatile variable.

Comment: Making `model` volatile will only provide a guarantee that if you write `model = new Model();` it will be visible by other threads. It does not guarantee that changes to its fields will be visible. In other words, it gives no guarantee that `model.state = someNewState;` will be visible from another thread. The other answer recommends using volatile on the `state` variable.